nvidia-persistenced service active but GPU not persisting
I have a slight problem getting PyTorch/Tensorflow to actually use the GPU installed on my box. Both fail on the CUDA init (cuInit) step.
I initially thought that that this was an ownership issue. /dev/nvidia* was owned by root:root while the PyTorch/Tensorflow scripts used to be run under my normal user who is not a member of root.
After going through the docs, I discovered that the problem occurred basically because the GPU connection wasn't being persisted and that NVIDIA has a persistence mode in order to solve this issue. There are two solutions - a legacy solution of running nvidia-smi -pm 1 as root or a daemon (nvidia-persistenced) that runs in userspace. The persistence docs say that the legacy solution might get phased out at any time so I decided to enable the nvidia-persistenced service under systemd so that I don't have to keep running su - && nvidia-smi -pm 1 every time I boot up the system. The Linux installation guide also mentions this as a recommended step.
I followed this page on the NVIDIA forums and setup the service. systemctl status nvidia-persistenced.service confirms that the service is active and running. But my PyTorch/Tensorflow scripts still cannot access the GPU. The only way they can access it is if I manually run
$ su -
# nvidia-smi -pm 1
# exit

I'm currently running Debian 12 Bookworm. My NVIDIA driver version is 535.183.01 and CUDA Toolkit version is 12.3. I'm on PyTorch version 2.4 and TensorFlow version 2.17.
Could someone point me in a direction that helps me with solving this issue? The systemd service file is below
[Unit]
Description=NVIDIA Persistence Daemon
Wants=syslog.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced --persistence-mode --user debian
ExecStopPost=/bin/rm -rf /var/run/nvidia-persistenced

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


The systemd status is
root@debian:~# systemctl status nvidia-persistenced.service 
● nvidia-persistenced.service - NVIDIA Persistence Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nvidia-persistenced.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/nvidia-persistenced.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-07-30 11:19:18 IST; 35min ago
   Main PID: 3803 (nvidia-persiste)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38180)
     Memory: 432.0K
        CPU: 5ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/nvidia-persistenced.service
             └─3803 /usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced --persistence-mode --user debian

Jul 30 11:19:18 debian systemd[1]: Starting nvidia-persistenced.service - NVIDIA Persistence Da>
Jul 30 11:19:18 debian systemd[1]: Started nvidia-persistenced.service - NVIDIA Persistence Dae>
Jul 30 11:19:18 debian nvidia-persistenced[3803]: Started (3803)

